# Google Data Studio: How Can I select only one day in the Date Range filter

Tags: date-range, looker-studio

I want to create a daily report for some metrics with Google Data Studio.
However, when I add a range filter I can only select a range of days.

I have some questions about it:
1) Is there some way to only select one day in date filter? 
2) I have no data before May-2018. Can I delete days before this date?

I have tried to use a filter control instead of a Date range filter with the Date column in the dimension of the filter. 
However I cannot make it work because when I select for this filter: 
Default date range, Auto (May 1 2019, today) I do not know how can I show the info from "today" instead of the whole range

Answer (score 2):

So there are a couple of single selection which are single days - today and yesterday. These are available via a drop-down in the top-right of the date selection.

You can also select a single day by selecting the same date on both Start date and End date.

[image: Date drop down]

You can also change the default selection in the Edit mode by clicking on the Date filter and then changing the date in the "Data" section on the right panel

[image: Data date drop down]